# Kubuntu corrupt screen after lid close/screensaver

Tags: kubuntu, screen, flicker

I've seen a few other Q&As around this, but nothing that is exactly what I'm experiencing.

I have a new Lenovo X220 which I'm running the latest Kubuntu on.  If I close the lid when I open it I get, 9/10 times, a flickering screen which sometimes updates around where the mouse is currently pointing and sometimes draws the wrong thing (i.e. it draws a program which is actually in the background)

Normally I've resorted to just rebooting if this is the case but I want to know if there is a better way of doing it?

Display drivers (`lspci | grep VGA`):

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
```

Comment: Have had a similar issue on Ubuntu 11.04. Starts with login and won't go without a restart.

Comment: what display drivers are you using?

Comment: You'll likely have to wait until Ubuntu 11.10 for the problem to be fixed, unless you're willing to install a newer kernel and a newer version of the Intel X driver. The versions in Ubuntu 11.04 only have basic support for the new Sandy Bridge graphics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to reinstall and this fixed the issue!

Answer (score 1):

Do you happen to use Desktop Effects? Most display issues go away if I toggle desktop effects off/on by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> twice. If graphics effects are still buggy, I disable desktop effects.

Sometimes, the issue goes away if I disable desktop effects, start a full-screen application like [Hedgewars](http://packages.ubuntu.com/Hedgewars)[image: Install Hedgewars], from there enable graphics effects and exit hedgewars.

Comment: typically my computer hasn't messed up since I posted this message - hence no accepted click yet but I'm eager to try your answer.  fingers crossed!