# Desktop Flickering after Suspend or Sleep

Tags: display, suspend

I seem to be experiencing some issues around my desktop display when my monitor has gone to sleep or I've suspended my system. Not always the case, but trying to turn it back on by moving my mouse, makes the entire desktop and logon screen unusable. I've been struggling to find a proper fix for this, and after reading this post:

[Kubuntu corrupt screen after lid close/screensaver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52172/kubuntu-corrupt-screen-after-lid-close-screensaver/52175#52175)

I believe it may have something to do with Desktop Effects. I do enjoy my effects, but if that's the fix, then I'll gladly do it. I have however found another way of getting around this. In the past I used to have to shut down or restart my machine to get the display working properly again, but I had a bunch of apps open and didn't want to lose work, so logged on via console, and then ran "startx". This created a new desktop on TTY8, and logged me on. When I revert back to TTY 7 (Ctrl+Alt+F7) the display no longer flickers, and I can log on without any problems.

If anyone has found any proven proper solution to bypass this issue, any assistance would be appreciated.

...

From further findings, this is yet to prove that it has anything to do with my desktop effects. It still happens without any effects enabled. Switching console windows, fixes the issue most of the time, but it means I have to go through each console up until it stops working, and I have to reboot.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ready to sacrifice the Effects then install Compiz available [here](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/compizconfig-settings-manager/).Disable all the "Effects".I hope your problem will be solved.